# Concatenating Rows and Column using Group_concat

Tags: mysql

i've been using group concat and concat separately in order to concatenate rows or column. However, i want to concatenate now both column data as well as the row such as:

From these given table

```
id  disease     domain
--  -------    --------
1   Typhoid     Davao City
2   Pox         Davao City
3   Dengue      Manila City
```

I want the sql to output this:

```
disease                 domain
-------              --------------
Typhoid: 1, Pox: 1   Davao City
Dengue: 1            Manila City
```

The task was concatenate or group all the diseases reported in a city, then count how many reports for each disease for each city. I know it sounds useless, but it's only given to me as an assignment, and I'm lost.

Comment: Where is "Tagum" in the result coming from? Should that be "Manila City"?

Comment: i've updated the question, that was wrong input, sorry. also, rather than displaying the domain, i want it to display the count.

Comment: it's really weird task but the problem tasked to me is to group the disease that belong to a city then count how many cases are there for each disease in each city. :/

Comment: OK, so let's see what you've tried.

Comment: I'm really lost. I could only concatenate typhoid and pox for example, but i could not perform count.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( disease,  ': ') 
SEPARATOR  '\n' )     --------> this works on concatenating the diseases for each city, but when i tried to perform count, it turns out to be an error

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' ',disease,total))
     , domain 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT disease
            , domain
            , COUNT(*) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP  
           BY domain
            , disease
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY domain;
```